# How to get the total number of comments on a LinkedIn company share?

Tags: linkedin-api

Using the LinkedIn REST API, we can get the updates for a specific company:

```
curl 'https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/1337/updates?format=json&oauth2_access_token=...'
```

Each update entry looks like this:

```
...
"isCommentable": true,
"isLikable": true,
"likes": {
    "_total": 3,
    "values": [
        ...
    ]
},
"numLikes": 304,
"updateComments": {
    "_total": 3,
    "values": [
        ...
    ]
}
...
```

Note that we get the total number of likes (numLikes), but we don't get the total number of comments (numComments would be great).
We cannot use the "_total" entry either, because it only gives the number of comments in the snippet.

We could ask for the comments on a specific update:

```
curl 'https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/1337/updates/key=.../update-comments?format=json&oauth2_access_token=...'
```

But there are two limitations:

1. We have to make one API call for each update, which is difficult because of the throttle limit.
2. We can only get the 100 first comments, since this URL does not support ?start= parameter. So if there are more than 100 comments there is no way to know the total.

Is there any other way to get the total number of comments for company updates?

Comment: I am looking for the same scenario.. We can only get the 100 first comments, since this URL does not support ?start= parameter. So if there are more than 100 comments there is no way to know the total. Is there any other way to get the total number of companies for company updates. Please suggest me